# MySQL Illegal mix of collations when using user-defined variables inside LOCATE

Tags: mysql, sql, locate, mysql-variables

I have a query like below to remove from a table column certain substrings which begin and end with particular substrings:

```
UPDATE om_posts SET post_content=REPLACE(post_content, SUBSTRING(
    post_content, 
    LOCATE(' style="', post_content), 
    LOCATE('"', post_content, LOCATE(' style="', post_content  )+ 8) - LOCATE(' style="', post_content ) + 1
),'')
where post_type="post";
```

I want to make this better reusable, so I'd like to abstract out those strings. I came across user-defined variables in mysql and refactored like this:

```
SET @beginning = ' style="';
SET @ending ='"';

UPDATE om_posts SET post_content=REPLACE(post_content, SUBSTRING(
    post_content, 
    LOCATE(@beginning, post_content), 
    LOCATE(@ending, post_content, LOCATE(@beginning, post_content  )+ 8) - LOCATE(@beginning, post_content ) + 1
),'')
where post_type="post";
```

but this gives an error: `Error in query (1267): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'locate'`. As far as I can tell my syntax should be correct. What am I missing?

Comment: I've had very few collation issues I've needed to resolve; but perhaps this will help. [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-literal.html) _It seems to focus on `SELECT`s with literals, but could probably be applied to values used on the right-hand of `SET` operations._

Comment: @Uueerdo excellent, thanks for your help. I'm pretty nooby at SQL. I just explicitly declared collaction to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for both, and it worked. If you want to add your answer, I'll accept it :P

Comment: Sometimes experience just means knowing the right search terms. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Every character string literal has a character set and a collation.
>
> For the simple statement SELECT 'string', the string has the
>   connection default character set and collation defined by the
>   character_set_connection and collation_connection system variables.
>
> A character string literal may have an optional character set
>   introducer and COLLATE clause, to designate it as a string that uses a
>   particular character set and collation:
>
> [_charset_name]'string' [COLLATE collation_name]

from the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-literal.html)

example from that page: `_utf8mb4'abc' COLLATE utf8mb4_danish_ci`